# Align div wider than screen to be center & hidden overflow

Tags: html, css

I want to make slideshow which wider than monitor screen.

Below codes is if the div smaller than screen:

The HTML:

```
<div class="testme">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html,body{
    padding:0;margin:0;
}

.testme{
    width:400px;height:300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But if the `img` width wider than monitor screen, I must remove `width` in CSS to make overflow works. But `width` is important for align center.

Use `margin-left: -50%` do aligning it but not exactly centered

(Most slider I know use html `img` and not background, which is problem if I want the slider wider than screen)

Comment: Why do you have to remove width to make overflow work? What is the question exactly?

Comment: You can see the difference between http://jsfiddle.net/2Xzs5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/4ta4T/1/

Comment: you are not defining the `overflow` property in your css so I am confused by what you mean when you say "I must remove `width` in CSS to make overflow works"?

Comment: both fiddles look the same to me, image goes off screen to the right in same position

Comment: It's not same. Look carefully at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it ll help you.. but in case you just want to make the image at the center of the div..
u can put the image in background property of the div and position it to center.. u don't need to worry about margin or anything.. if the div increases in size according to screen where u r viewing ..it ll readjust to best case center..

```
.testme {
background: url('..src of image tag');
background-position:center;
}
```

in case you need it for the slideshow.. you can always dynamically add the background property to the div tag and remove the image tag from the div. :)
hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
img {
    width: 120%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: -10%; /*half of width surplus*/
}
```